# Redirect and modify URLs in Chrome when matched

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The Question is when I click on a Youtube link, Can it be redirected to *[www.Youtube-nocookie.com](http://www.Youtube-nocookie.com)*. Recommend please **Javascript** or **Chrome Extension**

I have a sample bookmark Javascript that on clicking redirects to Youtube-Nocookie.com/embed/VideoID.

```
    javascript: 
    var URL = location.href;
    var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = URL.match(regExp); 
        if (match&&match[7].length==11{
          videoID=match[7];
          window.open('https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/'+videoID+'?autoplay=1');
     } else { 
          window.open('https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/');
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting the videoID on clicking the link?

Comment: Yeah It opens it in new Tab being concatenated with _https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/_ . @user2181397

Comment: You can see `var URL=location.href;` that means only if videoID is present in **url** of the Browser @user2181397

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switcheroo-redirector/cnmciclhnghalnpfhhleggldniplelbg?hl=en

I tested it quickly and seems to be able to replace the url to whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks,Solved With it!